# vb.net - Generating number 0 to N, puts in array, and it my program freezes

Tags: vb.net

I want to randomly generate numbers between 0 to 5 and put them in array(with 6 size) but when the randomly generated number is 0 it skips so leaving my array only has 1 to 5, and it just generates infinitely finding other numbers beside 1 to 5, which absolutely result to freeze coz im just randomizing only from 0 to 5.

heres my code, i know the GoTo is 'oldschool and harmful' to coding based on my research, but just disregard it(or if u have better coding then feel free to revise my code XD):

```
Dim intNumber As Integer
Dim xP, yP As Integer

    'no period repeat
    For xP = 0 To 5
        If arrPeriod(xP) = Nothing Then '<--- this is why it does not include 0 to the array, making 0 equals to Nothing
Start:
            intNumber = GetRandom(0, 6)

            For yP = 0 To 5
                If intNumber = arrPeriod(yP) Then
                    GoTo Start
                End If
            Next yP
            arrPeriod(xP) = intNumber

        End If

    Next xP
```

with simulation that code will give me this result, e.g.

```
arrPeriod() = {1, 5, 4, 3, 2, ...infinite loop/freeze}
```

what I want is this

```
arrPeriod() = {5, 3, 2, 4, 1, 0}
```

Comment: What is the data type of arrPeriod?  Instead of using a for loop to check if the number already exists in the array, use the Contains method.  that way you can get rid of that inner FOR loop and also get rid of that nasty GOTO statement.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of populating the array with random numbers, 
populate it with all possible numbers and sort it in a random order. Using Linq it can be done in the same row:

```
Dim r As New Random
Dim arrPeriod As Integer() = Enumerable.Range(0, 6).OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToArray()
```

[Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3EpJ2i)

Comment: I get an error saying 1d array cannot be converted into int

Comment: Sorry, It's been a while since I've used VB.Net, I mostly write c# now... See my edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might have a problem with your index going from 0 to 5 in both loops.

Try this:

```
      Dim A() As Integer
      ReDim A(5)
      A(0) = CInt(Floor(6 * Rnd()))
      For i As Integer = 0 To 4
choose:  Dim value As Integer = CInt(Floor(6 * Rnd()))
         For j As Integer = 0 To i
            If value = A(j) Then GoTo choose
         Next
         A(i) = value
      Next
```

Comment: Downvoting without leaving a comment is not helpful, it's harmful. @Downvoter, care to explain?